# Find the corresponding [x,y] coordinates for a given z coordinate value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D array, and I were to find the greatest Z-coordinate in that array. After that I need to find the corresponding X and Y coordinate values based on the Z-coordinate. How can I achieve it quickly via numpy?

What I did:
I used argsort to first sort the given 3D array, then used np. max(array) to find the greatest Z-coordinate. I do not know how else to continue. Can numpy.where be useful here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is  [numpy argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)

quick example :

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(5,3)
print data
ind = np.argmax(data[:,2])
print data[ind, :]
```

outputs

```
[[0.92037795 0.59469121 0.02956843]
 [0.82881039 0.23272832 0.97275488]
 [0.98418468 0.45699429 0.44662552]
 [0.62519115 0.16637013 0.40433299]
 [0.98272718 0.01467489 0.57442259]]

[0.82881039 0.23272832 0.97275488]
```